# rgee: "An error occur when ee_install was creating the Python Environment"

Tags: python, r, rstudio, google-earth-engine, rgee

While trying to run this:

```
library(rgee)
rgee::ee_install()
```

I get the following error:

```
> library(rgee)
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'htmltools':
  method               from         
  print.html           tools:rstudio
  print.shiny.tag      tools:rstudio
  print.shiny.tag.list tools:rstudio
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'htmlwidgets':
  method           from         
  print.htmlwidget tools:rstudio
> rgee::ee_install()
───────────────── Python configuration used to create rgee ──
python:         C:/Users/my_user/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/my_user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python312.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/my_user/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate
version:        3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, Feb  6 2024, 21:26:36) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/my_user/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.26.4
ee:             [NOT FOUND]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
1. Removing the previous Python Environment (rgee), if it exists ...
rgee not found 


2. Creating a Python Environment (rgee)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  An error occur when ee_install was creating the Python Environment. Run ee_clean_pyenv() and restart the R session, before trying again.
```

I tried running `ee_clean_pyenv()` and restarting R I get the same result.

Any idea how to fix this?